# How to add cell which is long pressed to indexpathforSelectedRow?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cell, uilongpressgesturerecogni

I want to add a cell that longPressed to indexPathforSelectedRow.. 
when I longPress a cell, I hope it would be added automatically in indexPathForSelectedRow... how can I do it?

This code is long press function:

```
func longPress(longPressGestureRecognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {

 if longPressGestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended {

    let touchPoint = longPressGestureRecognizer.locationInView(self.view)
    if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(touchPoint) {
        let cellToDeSelect:UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)! 
     //then how? 
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use:

```
if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(touchPoint) {
    tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .None)
}
```

Comment: oh!! i am very grateful to you! actually i spent whole day to search a solution... but i never didn't find a solution.  but you did.. thanks a lot!! ^^